# How to use variable inside of CMD in dockerfile?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

As you can see in this Dockerfile, I do pass the PORT number as `--build-arg` at buildtime. Now I need to run `npx next start -p ${PORT}`:

```
FROM node:16.6.1-alpine3.14
RUN apk add dumb-init

ARG PORT

EXPOSE $PORT
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/dumb-init", "--"]
CMD ["npx", "next", "start", "-p", "echo ${PORT}"]
```

But this is not working. The app is running at the default 3000 port. If I do

```
CMD ["npx", "next", "start", "-p", "3100"]
```

The app is running at 3100 as expected. But why can't I use a variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format you are using (`exec`) won't work. From the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd):

> the exec form does not invoke a command shell. This means that normal shell processing does not happen.

Instead, you can execute a shell directly:

```
CMD ["sh", "-c", "npx next start -p $PORT"]
```

Comment: What is the difference to set an ENV? `ENV portValue=$PORT` and `CMD ["npx", "next", "start", "-p", "${portValue}"]`

Comment: But using the env, like I showed in the comment is working and your soluteion doesn't work, although I understand your code...

Comment: When you say it doesn't work.. do you get an error?

Comment: If you use `sh -c`, the entire command must be in the next shell word; `CMD ["sh", "-c", "npx next start ..."]`.  But Docker can insert the `sh -c` wrapper for you, `CMD npx next start ...`; you shouldn't usually need to spell out `sh -c` in a Dockerfile.

Comment: @DavidMaze Right, of course, thanks David

Comment: @DavidMaze What is the difference between `CMD ["sh"...]` and `CMD npx...`? What is the advantage of using `[...]`?

Comment: `CMD some command` is identical to `CMD ["sh", "-c", "some command"]`.  The exec form `CMD ["some", "command"]` avoids running a shell which can be marginally faster, and it's required in a couple of more complex cases ("distroless" images that don't have shells; most uses of `ENTRYPOINT` that respect `CMD`; `CMD` as arguments to the main container process).

Answer (score -2):

Setting a env variable and use this in the CMD:

```
ARG PORT
ENV portValue=$PORT
CMD ["npx", "next", "start", "-p", "${portValue}"]
```

Comment: With the exec syntax, there's no shell to expand that variable.